# unable to access kubernetes dashboard via token

Tags: dashboard, kubeadm, kubernetes

1. I have setup a kubernetes using kubeadm v1.8.5
2. Setup a dashboard using:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.8.0/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml`

kubectl create -f kubernetes-dashboard.yaml

kubectl create -f kubernetes-dashboard-admin.rbac.yaml
```

3. Then setup kubectl proxy, using `http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/`  as recommended.
4. When I am trying to login using kubernetes-dashboard-admin token. Token was received by using the command:

```
    kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep -i dashboard-admin | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I {} 
    kubectl -n kube-system describe secret {}
```

**Here comes my problem: I CANT access the dashboard via token, when I paste the token and click "Signin" botton, nothing happened. And I get nothing in my log[using tail -f /var/log/messages and journalctl -xeu kubelet]. I am a newbee on k8s, maybe someone could tell me where the log is?**
[image]

Here are my k8s cluster-info:

[root@k8s-1 pki]# `kubectl cluster-info`

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://172.16.1.15:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://172.16.1.15:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns/proxy
kubernetes-dashboard is running at https://172.16.1.15:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

[root@k8s-1 pki]# `kubectl get nodes`

```
NAME      STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
k8s-1     Ready     master    4d        v1.8.5
k8s-2     Ready     <none>    4d        v1.8.5
k8s-3     Ready     <none>    4d        v1.8.5
```

[root@k8s-1 pki]# `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   etcd-k8s-1                              1/1       Running   2          4d
kube-system   kube-apiserver-k8s-1                    1/1       Running   2          4d
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-k8s-1           1/1       Running   1          4d
kube-system   kube-dns-545bc4bfd4-94vxx               3/3       Running   3          4d
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-97frd                   1/1       Running   2          4d
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-bl9tp                   1/1       Running   2          4d
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-bn9hp                   1/1       Running   1          4d
kube-system   kube-proxy-9ncdm                        1/1       Running   0          4d
kube-system   kube-proxy-qjm9k                        1/1       Running   1          4d
kube-system   kube-proxy-rknz4                        1/1       Running   0          4d
kube-system   kube-scheduler-k8s-1                    1/1       Running   2          4d
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-7486b894c6-tszq9   1/1       Running   0          2h
```

The kubernetes-dashboard-admin-rbac.yaml is:

[root@k8s-1 dashboards]# `cat kubernetes-dashboard-admin.rbac.yaml`

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-admin
  namespace: kube-system
```

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-admin
  annotations:
    rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: "true"
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-admin
  namespace: kube-system
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!!!

Comment: to check the logs ... "kubectl logs -h" , you will find the help on how to use it

Answer (score 13):

Try connect with https, I have same problem, and this works for me

Kubernetes Manual:

> NOTE: Dashboard should not be exposed publicly using kubectl proxy
>   command as it only allows HTTP connection. For domains other than
>   localhost and 127.0.0.1 it will not be possible to sign in. Nothing
>   will happen after clicking Sign in button on login page. Logging in is
>   only available when accessing Dashboard over HTTPS or when domain is
>   either localhost or 127.0.0.1. It's done this way for security
>   reasons. Closing as this works as intended.

Answer (score 9):

Try This token (output):

```
 kubectl -n kube-system get secret |grep  kubernetes-dashboard-token |cut -f1 -d ' ' |  xargs kubectl -n kube-system describe  secret
```

if doesn't work try/test login with this token (output) :

```
kubectl -n kube-system get secret |grep  namespace-controller-token  |cut -f1 -d ' ' |  xargs kubectl -n kube-system describe  secret
```

Good luck..

Answer (score 3):

You should create an admin user first and add the cluster-admin clusterrolebinding to it:

Use these files [admin-user.yaml](https://github.com/tedsluis/kubernetes-via-kubeadm/blob/master/admin-user.yaml) and [admin-user-clusterrolebinding.yaml](https://github.com/tedsluis/kubernetes-via-kubeadm/blob/master/admin-user-clusterrolebinding.yaml) to create the admin user with the cluster-admin clusterrolebinding:

```
[root@k8s-1 kubernetes-via-kubeadm]# kubectl create -f admin-user.yaml
serviceaccount "admin-user" created

[root@k8s-1 kubernetes-via-kubeadm]# kubectl create -f admin-user-clusterrolebinding.yaml 
clusterrolebinding "admin-user" created
```

To get the token for this admin-user:

```
[root@k8s-1 kubernetes-via-kubeadm]# kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep admin-user | awk '{print $1}') | grep ^token: | sed 's/token:[ ]*/Token:\n/'
Token:
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJrdWJlcm5ldGVzL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9uYW1lc3BhY2UiOiJrdWJlLXN5c3RlbSIsImt1YmVybmV0ZXMuaW8vc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQvc2VjcmV0Lm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbi11c2VyLXRva2VuLW1oNzIyIiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9zZXJ2aWNlLWFjY291bnQubmFtZSI6ImFkbWluLXVzZXIiLCJrdWJlcm5ldGVzLmlvL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50L3NlcnZpY2UtYWNjb3VudC51aWQiOiIwNWM0ZDZmZC0yZjYyLTExZTgtYTMxNi1jMDNmZDU2MmJiNzciLCJzdWIiOiJzeXN0ZW06c2VydmljZWFjY291bnQ6a3ViZS1zeXN0ZW06YWRtaW4tdXNlciJ9.butKxegADx3JQvKpn9Prf7RL_SoxaEyi_scYOvXurm4BAwEj8zfC9a7djqQ9mBtd5cQHlljvMb-3qFc6UPOzAwR8fc5khk-nAkH-5XeahpT8WsyxMcKxqLuyAg8gh4ZtMKvBPk9kOWDtyRBzAeGkisbLxr43ecKO71F5G8D7HR2UGSm-x4Pvhq0uqj8GyIcHw902Ti92BPuBRf-SyTl8uDCQJSDkS5Tru5w0p82borNuVXd1mmDwuI87ApQrqXTY9rbJ61m8iTr0kKJBqw5bHAUAhxwAVtVEKQNNKT6cxWp1FlhHbNkM9bhcj1qj8bN1QCMjPWlWKj7NkPbbBAJthQ
```

You can use the token to login to your kubernetes-dashboard.

Comment: Close, but the namespace needs to be kubernetes-dashboard instead: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md

Answer (score 3):

I faced this problem recently after upgrading k8s version to 1.16. Normally, I was able to access dashboard on local without any login but after that upgrade, it started to open login page first and even though I used a valid token, it didn't let me into dashboard. (There was no response, the page was just stuck)

In order to resolve the issue firstly I removed dashboard related resources.

```
kubectl delete clusterrolebinding kubernetes-dashboard
```

Then I deployed the newest dashboard version with the following command.

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

After the above steps, I run proxy command again and this time, by entering the token, it proceeded with a dashboard page.

Edit: If you get cluster role related error and can't open any actual content, you may need to run the following commands:

```
kubectl delete clusterrolebinding kubernetes-dashboard
kubectl create clusterrolebinding kubernetes-dashboard --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:kubernetes-dashboard --user=clusterUser
```

Answer (score 0):

Run below two command :

sym@symserver:~/Downloads$ token=$(microk8s.kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep default-token | cut -d " " -f1)

sym@symserver:~/Downloads$ microk8s.kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $token

above command will generate token for dashboard access

Answer (score -1):

From my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50401176/3965439):

#### Get the service token

```
$ kubectl -o json get secret k8s-dashboard-sa-token-XXXXX | jq -r '.data.token' | base64 -d
eyJhbGci    ... sjcuNA8w
```