# How to integrate Kubernetes with Gitlab

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, rancher

I'm trying to integrate Kubernetes cluster with Gitlab for using the Gitlab Review Apps feature.

- Kubernetes cluster is created via Rancher 1.6
- Running the `kubectl get all` from the kubernetes shell gives

> ```
> NAME             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)        AGE
> svc/my-service   LoadBalancer   x.x.144.67     x.x.13.89   80:32701/TCP      30d
> svc/kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.43.0.1      <none>         443/TCP        30d
> ```

- On the Gitlab `CI / CD` > `Kubernetes` page, we need to enter mainly 3 fields:

  1. API URL
  2. CA Certificate
  3. Token

### API URL

- If I'm not wrong, we can get the Kubernetes API URL from `Rancher Dashboard` > `Kubernetes` > `CLI` > `Generate Config` and copy the `server` url under `cluster`

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Config
> clusters:
> - cluster:
>     api-version: v1
>     insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
>     server: "https://x.x.122.197:8080/r/projects/1a7/kubernetes:6443"
> ```

### CA Certificate & Token?

- Now, the question is, where to get the CA Certificate (pem format) and the Token?

I tried all the `ca.crt` and `token` values from all the namespaces from the Kubernetes dashboard, but I'm getting this error on the Gitlab when trying to install `Helm Tiller` application:

> ```
> Something went wrong while installing Helm Tiller
>
> Can't start installation process
> ```

Here is how my secrets page look like
[image]

Answer (score 17):

I'm also dying out with kubernetes and GitLab. I've created a couple single-node "clusters" for testing, one with [`minikube`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/) and another via [`kubeadm`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/).

I answered this question on the [GitLab forum](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/kubernetes-integration-something-went-wrong-while-installing-helm-tiller/15627/3) but I'm posting my solution below:

#### API URL

According to the [official documentation](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/clusters/index.md#adding-an-existing-kubernetes-cluster), the API URL is only `https://hostname:port` without trailing slash

#### List secrets

First, I listed the secrets as usual:

```
$ kubectl get secrets
NAME                           TYPE                                  DATA      AGE
default-token-tpvsd            kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3         2d
k8s-dashboard-sa-token-XXXXX   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3         1d
```

#### Get the service token

```
$ kubectl -o json get secret k8s-dashboard-sa-token-XXXXX | jq -r '.data.token' | base64 -d
eyJhbGci    ... sjcuNA8w
```

#### Get the CA certificate

Then I got the CA certificate directly from the JSON output via jq with a custom selector:

```
$ kubectl -o json get secret k8s-dashboard-sa-token-XXXXX | jq -r '.data."ca.crt"' | base64 -d - | tee ca.crt
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICyDCCAbCgAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAVMRMwEQYDVQQDEwprdWJl
...        ...        ...        ...        ...        ...      
FT55iMtPtFqAOnoYBCiLH6oT6Z1ACxduxPZA/EeQmTUoRJG8joczI0V1cnY=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

#### Verity the CA certificate

With the CA certificate on hand you can `verify` as usual:

```
$ openssl x509 -in ca.crt -noout -subject -issuer
subject= /CN=kubernetes
issuer= /CN=kubernetes

$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect 192.168.100.20:6443 < /dev/null &> apiserver.crt

$ openssl verify -verbose -CAfile ca.crt apiserver.crt
apiserver.crt: OK
```

Comment: Mine validates and I still get "Something went wrong while installing Helm Tiller"

Comment: Mine does not validate. What are some reasons or techniques to determine the problem?